# glBufferData with explicit array vs non explicit array

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm creating a glBufferData using an array explicitly defined of vertex coordinates and everything works fine. When using a non explicitly defined array the result is totally different althought I'm using the same coordinates values. The drawcall renders things in a different vertexs order.

The vertexs are a grid of triangles.

Code 1 that works fine:

```
this->graphics->createBuffers(1, vboIndexsID);
this->graphics->bindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, *vboIndexsID);
this->graphics->bufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLushort)*numIndexs, ind, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

this->graphics->createBuffers(1, vboVertexsID);
this->graphics->bindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, *vboVertexsID);

this->graphics->bufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 300, quad_verts2, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

where quad_verts2 is:

```
GLfloat quad_verts2[75] =
{
    0.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f, 
    0.0f,   0.0f, 100.0f, 
    0.0f,   0.0f, 200.0f, 
    0.0f,   0.0f, 300.0f, 
    0.0f,   0.0f, 400.0f, 
    100.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 
    100.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, 
    100.0f, 0.0f, 200.0f, 
    100.0f, 0.0f, 300.0f, 
    100.0f, 0.0f, 400.0f, 
    200.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 
    200.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, 
    200.0f, 0.0f, 200.0f, 
    200.0f, 0.0f, 300.0f, 
    200.0f, 0.0f, 400.0f, 
    300.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 
    300.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, 
    300.0f, 0.0f, 200.0f, 
    300.0f, 0.0f, 300.0f, 
    300.0f, 0.0f, 400.0f, 
    400.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 
    400.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, 
    400.0f, 0.0f, 200.0f, 
    400.0f, 0.0f, 300.0f, 
    400.0f, 0.0f, 400.0f
};
```

Code 2 that doesn't work:

```
this->graphics->createBuffers(1, vboIndexsID);
this->graphics->bindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, *vboIndexsID);
this->graphics->bufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLushort)*numIndexs, ind, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

this->graphics->createBuffers(1, vboVertexsID);
this->graphics->bindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, *vboVertexsID);

this->graphics->bufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 300, list, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

exactly the same as before, but the list data instead of quad_vert2.

where list is:

```
GLfloat list[75];
int j = 0;
for(int i=0;i<numVertexs;++i) {
    list[j] = v->coord.x;j++;
    list[j] = v->coord.y;j++;
    list[j] = v->coord.z;j++;
    ++v;
}
```

the data in v, is exactly the same values than in quad_vert2.

glGetError, after glBufferData is always 0.
If I get the data in the buffer using glGetBufferSubData the values are the same.

Ideas?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you forget to assign `numVertexs`?

Comment: Nope. The data in list and in quad_vert2 has the same values with the inspector.

Comment: First of all: GLfloat* list = new GLfloat[numVertices*3];

Comment: @Frizi: Yuck!  No need for memory leaks here.

Comment: With quad_verts2 I can see 25 points in the screen, with list only 9.

Comment: Then the problem is in the code you haven't shown.

Comment: @BenVoigt Then just delete[] :) Proper memory management is an art, but we really don't want the buffer overflow.

Comment: @Frizi: Of course, but then just `GLfloat list[numVertices*3];` should be good enough.  And manual `delete[]` isn't so simple, it breaks both exception safety and early return.

Comment: @BenVoigt This is not standard C++. This is valid in C99, but C++ does not inhirit this behavior. Although some compilers does accept this as an extension. You could always use the auto_ptr if you need the exception safety. Early returns are not an issue IMHO. They are just a bad code, if used in function before cleanup (still, IMHO).

Comment: @Frizi: `auto_ptr`?  You seem a few years out of date on C++.  I see no reason to think that `numVertices` isn't a constant, and if it is variable, then `std::vector` would be a good choice, followed by `std::unique_ptr`.  I can't think of any case in which I'd recommend manual allocation for this.

Comment: @BenVoigt You are right, auto_ptr is bad today, but now there are unique_ptr and shared_ptr. Anyway, vectors ftw in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I would be suspect of the value of `numVertexs`, since your buffer data upload call does not actually use it. You should be uploading `sizeof (GLfloat) * 3 * numVertexs` bytes of data and not using the magic number `300`. If you replace `300` with that expression in both situations chances are good that it will expose your real problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all,

the problem here was: 
I was rendering two objects, with different number of vertexs. When rendering, I forgot to assign the indexs buffer correctly, and openGL was trying to draw the second object with the indexs of the first one.